# Conditional binding attribute in Facelet tag file/JSF

Tags: jsf, binding, tagfile

In my JSF 2.1 project i defined a custom tag file which includes a `h:inputText` element. This element may or may not include a `binding` attribute – depending on the passed parameters of the custom element.

Example formInput.xhtml (excerpt):

```html
<h:inputText id="#{id}" value="#{value}">
    <c:if test="#{not empty binding}">
        <f:attribute name="binding" value="#{binding}"/>
    </c:if>
</h:inputText>
```

Usage from other file:

```html
<e:formInput id="test" value="#{testBean.myValue}" binding="#{testBean.myBinding}"/>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. `#{not empty binding}` resolves to false and the binding is not applied.

However, defining the `binding` attribute without a condition **does** work.
Example:

```html
<h:inputText id="#{id}" value="#{value}">
    <f:attribute name="binding" value="#{binding}"/>
</h:inputText>
```

In this case the binding is applied correctly.

Does anyone know how to set the binding conditionally?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion using binding is a hack. My advice would be to solve your underlaying problem differently. That being said, there is a workaround for your conditional binding issue, using "brace notation" and a fallback binding object. Instead of passing the object to bind to, pass it's name (a `String`), this allows you to bind it like:

```html
<h:inputText binding="#{testBean[objectName]}"/>
```

Brace notation also makes it possible to conditionally pass a property:

```html
<h:inputText binding="#{testBean[empty objectName ? 'fallback' : objectName]}"/>
```

This requires you to have a fallback binding object available at `#{testBean.fallback}`.

See also:

- [How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used)
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info